# I tried 'interp2' to measure the intensity of a line in octave but I have a method error, any suggestions

Tags: octave

```
imshow(matrix(:,:,1))
%identify axes
[x y] = ginput(2);
% preallocate matrices
cog = zeros(size(matrix,3),1);
%cog
% loop start
for i = 1:size(maytrix,3)
    I = matrix(:,:,i);
    %n = ceil(norm([diff(x), diff(y)]));  % A rough estimation of number of points
    test = interp2(I, 2, linspace(x(1), x(2),n), linspace(y(1), y(2),n));
    %test = round(test);
    cog(i) = sum((1:length(test)).*test')/sum(test);
    % loop end
end

scog = (cog - min(cog)) / (max(cog) - min(cog));
```

Comment: Please take the [tour] and read [ask]. Your questions about code, i.e. debugging questions like these, are served by not only providing the code + error message, but also a textual description on what the code is supposed to do, and what it currently does, see [mcve]. Also showing what you have already tried to solve the problem is appreciated. Please [edit] the question accordingly. Also read up on [formatting your posts](https://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting) for future reference, see the revision history on this post for an example.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a toy example to get you started.

```octave
% Create a 100x100x100 3D matrix with a certain pattern

% Smooth pattern:
  matrix = [1 : 100] .' * [1 : 100];
  matrix = matrix(:) * [1 : 100];
  matrix = reshape( matrix, 100, 100, 100 );

% Alternatively, try a random matrix:
  %matrix = randn(100,100,100);

Endpoints  = randi( [1, 100], [3, 2] );   % Randomly get 2 3D points within matrix
Numpoints  = max( abs( diff( Endpoints, 1, 2 ) ) );  % Choose width of widest dimension

% Create a line in 3D space (containing N points) going from one Endpoint to the other.
Linepoints = [ linspace( Endpoints(1, 1), Endpoints(1, 2), Numpoints );
               linspace( Endpoints(2, 1), Endpoints(2, 2), Numpoints );
               linspace( Endpoints(3, 1), Endpoints(3, 2), Numpoints ); ];

InterpolatedIntensities = interp3( 1:100, 1:100, 1:100, matrix, Linepoints(1, :), Linepoints(2, :), Linepoints(3, :) );

plot( InterpolatedIntensities );
```